# $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion problem

Tags: functions

Please, find bellow my original question.
Here is all my code:

```
vm = 5;
r0 = 127.25;
di = r0*2;
de = 273;
v = 0.000000464;
ρf = 958;
ρt = 7854;
pr = 2.88;
kf = 0.656;
kt = 58;
cf = 4186;
ct = 470;
re = (vm*(2*r0/1000)/v)
e = 0.00015;
f = 1.325 (Log[0.27*(e/(2*r0/1000)) + 5.74*(1/re)^0.9])^(-2)
tinf = 298;
tme = 373;
αf = kf/(ρf*cf)
c1 = (-f*ρf*vm^2/(4*r0/1000))
g = 9.81;
β = 1/((tme + tinf)/2)
var = 0.000018;
prar = 0.703;
α = 0.000025;
kar = 0.028;

ym[r_] := (((r0/1000) - r)*vm*(f/8)^(0.5))/v;
εm[r_] := v*(0.4*ym[r]/6)*(1 + (r/(r0/1000)))*(1 + 2*(r/(r0/1000))^2);

momento = NDSolve[{(1/r)*D[(v + εm[r])*r*D[u[r], r], r] == (1/ρf)*c1, u'[0.0000001] == 0, u[(r0/1000)] == 0},u[r], {r, -0.0000001, (r0/1000)}, MaxSteps -> 10000];
mom[r_] = u[r] /. First[momento];

hi = (kf/(2*r0/1000))*((re - 1000)*pr*(f/8))/(1 + 12.7*(f/8)^0.5*(pr^(2/3) - 1))
ra = (g*β*((tme + tinf)/2 - tinf)*(de/1000)^3)/(var*α);
he = (kar/(de/1000))*(0.6 + (0.387*ra^(1/6))/(1 + (0.559/prar)^(9/16))^(8/27))^2
```

Here starts my problem. Mathematica isn't able to solve systems of PDEs with more than one independent variable. But Mathematica is able to solve each one individually. So, I have to solve iteratively both the two equation varying a boundary condition (by the way, it is a partial elliptic equation). But, at the moment this is not the problem.

```
l = 200;
tempo = 100;
Clear[tmed]; 
Clear[tmedpred]; 
Clear[ttf]; 
Clear[med];
Clear[tpred]; 
tmed[x_, t_] := tinf; (*Initial*)
med[x_, t_] := tinf; (*Initial*)
tmedpred[x_, t_] := tinf; (*Initial*)
tpred[x_, t_] := tinf; (*Initial*)
ttf[x_, r_, t_] := tinf; (*Initial*)
subrel = 0.4;
eps = 10^-4;

(*While[erro\[GreaterEqual]eps,*)

enf1 = NDSolve[{(ρf*cf*(D[tf[x, r, t], t] + mom[r]*D[tf[x, r, t], x])) == ((1/r)*
   D[(r*(αf + εm[r])*D[tf[x, r, t], r]), r]),tf[x, r, 0] == (tme - tinf)*Exp[-1000*x] + tinf,tf[0, r, t] == tme, (D[tf[x, r, t], r] /. r -> 0.0000001) == 
 0, -kf*(D[tf[x, r, t], r] /. r -> (r0/1000)) == (1 - Exp[-1000*x])*hi*(tmed[x, t] - ttf[x, r0/1000, t])},tf[x, r, t], {x, 0, l}, {r, 0.0000001, (r0/1000)}, {t, 0, tempo}, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> 13}}];
tff[x_, r_, t_] = tf[x, r, t] /. First[enf1];

med[x_, t_] := (NIntegrate[(mom[r]*tff[x, r, t]*r), {r, 0.0000001, r0/1000}])*2/((2/((r0/1000)^2)*NIntegrate[(mom[r]*r), {r, 0.0000001, r0/1000}])*(r0/   1000)^2));

tpred[x_, t_] := tmedpred[x, t] + subrel*(med[x, t] - tmedpred[x, t]);
tmed[x_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := tpred[x, t];

ent1 = NDSolve[{ρt*ct*(D[tt[x, r, t], t]) == (1/r)*(D[(r*kt*D[tt[x, r, t], r]), r]), tt[x, r, 0] == tinf, -kt*(D[tt[x, r, t], r] /. r -> (r0/1000)) == (1 - Exp[-1000*x])*hi*(tmed[x, t] - ttf[x, r0/1000, t]), -kt*(D[tt[x, r, t], r] /. r -> (de/2000)) == (1 - Exp[-1000*t])*he*(ttf[x, de/2000, t] - tinf)}, tt[x, r, t], {x, 0, l}, {r, (r0/1000), (de/2000)}, {t, 0, tempo}];

tmedpred = tmed
```

Here is the problem. "tmedpred" shall return to the structure of the first NDSolve (enf1) and the code keep the loop up to an error value. Realize that the While structure is not in the code. I'm doing a manual evaluation.

The error: $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>
The box message: "A very large output was generated. Here is a sample of it: (<<1>>) + subrel (med[100, 50] - tmedpred[100, 50])

The problem starts with the input  tmedpred = tmed

(original question)
 I have two function:

```
med[x_?NumericQ, 
   t_?NumericQ] := ((NIntegrate[(mom[r]*tff[x, r, t]*r), {r, 
       0, 
       r0/1000}])*(2/((2/((r0/1000)^2)*
          NIntegrate[(mom[r]*r), {r, 0, r0/1000}])*(r0/
           1000)^2)));
```

and,

```
tmed[x_, t_] := tmedpred[x, t] + subrel*(med[x, t] - tmedpred[x, t]);
```

`mom[r]` and `tff[x,r,t]` are `NDSolve` output.

This functions are inside a While code and at the end of the loop,

`tmedpred = tmed` (`tmedpred` become `tmed` and the While code should keep iterating up to an error value)

`tmedpred[187,100]` (it is a simple evaluation of the function)

At this moment the warning

> "$RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded."

And a box with the message

> "A very large output was generated. Here is a sample of it:"
>
> (<<1>>) + subrel (med[187, 100] - tmedpred[187, 100])) +   subrel
>   (med[187, 100] - tmedpred[187, 100])

Could some one help me with this problem? 
I was wondering if it is possible to create a function that is not connected to the original function but keep its original behavior(a kind of numerical function).

Regards!

Comment: Please format your code and post a complete working example to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Post your whole code which produce error

Comment: Could some one help me? @molekyla777 ?

Comment: @Bill, the publication "Advanced Numerical Differential Equation Solving in Mathematica" says that in the case of PDEs, systems are possible only for one independent variable. I tried, but the output is a message like "it is not an ODE system". A plot of "momento" show me that it is ok. There is a discontinuity very closed to 0 and that is why I'm integrating from 0.0000001 to (r0/1000). My only problem (I think) is when I do tmedpred = tmed and the $RecursionLimit error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Updating mutually dependent functions at each iteration

It seems like one important aspect which leads to the circular dependency problem here ([pointed out earlier](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56933/117)) is that you want to update your function definitions for `tmed`, `tmedpred`, `ttf`, `med`, and `tpred` at each iteration.

Your code uses global rules to create and define your functions (e.g. `f[x_] := ...`). Updating a definition that is created as a global rule is going to be hard or problematic when it is used in the definition of another global-rule function used to redefine it.

I think a good alternative approach in this case is to create your functions as `Function` objects. This will make it easier to update them with a simple Set (e.g. `f = Function[{x, t}, ...]; oldf = f`).

However, you'll also need to make sure that when you create and/or update your definitions, the underlying functions that the current definition depends on are "captured" in their plain `Function`-object form, rather than as their symbolic names; otherwise, the circular dependency problem will remain.

In order to do this "capturing", I've provided a helper function (`captureValues`) at the end of this post.

The following listing is a revised version of your second section of code. It has a couple of typos corrected, and it uses the approach described above to store and update your function definitions for each iteration:

```
l = 200;
tempo = 100;
Clear[tmed];
Clear[tmedpred];
Clear[ttf];
Clear[med];
Clear[tpred];

(* Use Function objects for iteratively updated function definitions *)
tmed = tinf &;(*Initial*)
med = tinf &;(*Initial*)
tmedpred = tinf &;(*Initial*)
tpred = tinf &;(*Initial*)
ttf = tinf &;(*Initial*)
(* Each time one of these functions is updated with another Function \
object, it should use a "snapshot" of any Function object or normal \
value it depends on. This snapshotting can be done with a helper \
function. *)

subrel = 0.4;
eps = 10^-4;

(* NumericQ-guarded rule-form version of tmed *)
Clear[tmedNum];
(* Always delegates to tmed; tmed itself will be updated each time *)
tmedNum[x_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := tmed[x, t];

(*While[erro\[GreaterEqual]eps,*)

enf1 = NDSolveValue[{(\[Rho]f*
       cf*(D[tf[x, r, t], t] + mom[r]*D[tf[x, r, t], x])) == ((1/r)*
       D[(r*(\[Alpha]f + \[CurlyEpsilon]m[r])*D[tf[x, r, t], r]), r]),
     tf[x, r, 0] == (tme - tinf)*Exp[-1000*x] + tinf, 
    tf[0, r, t] == tme, (D[tf[x, r, t], r] /. r -> 0.0000001) == 
     0, -kf*(D[tf[x, r, t], r] /. r -> (r0/1000)) == (1 - 
        Exp[-1000*x])*hi*(tmed[x, t] - ttf[x, r0/1000, t])}, 
   tf, {x, 0, l}, {r, 0.0000001, (r0/1000)}, {t, 0, tempo}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> 13}}];

ttf = enf1;

med =
  Function[{x, t},
    (NIntegrate[(mom[r]*ttf[x, r, t]*r), {r, 0.0000001, 
        r0/1000}])*2/((2/((r0/1000)^2)*
          NIntegrate[(mom[r]*r), {r, 0.0000001, r0/1000}])*(r0/1000)^2)
    ] // captureValues;

tpred =
  Function[{x, t},
    tmedpred[x, t] + subrel*(med[x, t] - tmedpred[x, t])
    ] // captureValues;

tmed = tpred;

ent1 = NDSolve[{\[Rho]t*
      ct*(D[tt[x, r, t], t]) == (1/r)*(D[(r*kt*D[tt[x, r, t], r]), 
        r]), tt[x, r, 0] == 
     tinf, -kt*(D[tt[x, r, t], r] /. r -> (r0/1000)) == (1 - 
        Exp[-1000*x])*
      hi*(tmedNum[x, t] - 
        ttf[x, r0/1000, t]), -kt*(D[tt[x, r, t], r] /. 
        r -> (de/2000)) == (1 - Exp[-1000*t])*
      he*(ttf[x, de/2000, t] - tinf)}, 
   tt[x, r, t], {x, 0, l}, {r, (r0/1000), (de/2000)}, {t, 0, tempo}];

tmedpred = tmed;
```

With the function evaluations now made independent of the function symbols that were used to define them, no circularity occurs:

```
In[231]:= tmedpred[187, 100]

Out[231]= 328.
```

However, fixing the circularity problem reveals an error arising from the input of the `NDSolve` expression for `ent1`:

[image: Errors from ent1 NDSolve evaluation]

I'm no expert with PDEs, so you may have to pick it up from here `:-)`

#### Capturing Function objects to prevent circular dependency

Here is an example of a helper function `captureValues` that can be used to create "independent" `Function` objects from ones that depend on other `Function` objects (and "normal" values i.e. values with non-empty `OwnValues`).

```
ClearAll[evaluateSymbols, captureValues]

evaluateSymbols = # //. s_Symbol :> With[{ss = s}, ss /; True] &;

captureValues[f : HoldPattern@Function[_ | PatternSequence[, __]]] :=
  evaluateSymbols@f

captureValues[f : HoldPattern@Function[params : {___Symbol}, __]] :=
  Block[params, evaluateSymbols@f]
```

Some example tests:

```
testf1 = Total@{##} &;

testf2 = testf1 @@ #1/#2 &;

testf3 = Function[{x, y}, x + y + testf2[{x, y}, y]];

x = 3; (* to show that same-named parameters are preserved *)

captureValues@testf3

(* Out: Function[{x, y}, x + y + ((Total[{##1}] &) @@ #1/#2 &)[{x, y}, y]] *)
```

**Edit:**

A general note about the "value capturing" helper function above: It only protects the outermost `Function`'s parameters from replacement, and thus doesn't work in all cases when there are in-scope ownvalues for parameter symbols of nested functions. Furthermore, it doesn't take [any other scoping construct](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ScopingConstructs.html) into account. A full solution for this capturing idea is doable I think, but non-trivial (and probably a good suggestion to file with WRI Support).

Comment: Thanks a lot @billisphere, this is really useful for me. As you can realize, I'm not able to do an elegant code in Mathematica. In other hand, Mathematica has been saving me in my master degree. By the way, I'm an expert in the "NDSolve ibcinc" warning. :)

Comment: @LuisFernandoMoura, no problem, glad to have been able to help. You might want to take a look at the edit I just made to introduce an updated helper function. My first attempt at the helper function was bloated and wrong in an important case that it was trying to cover (when a `Function` has a parameter with the same name as a previously set symbol). It still worked for your example because that case didn't come up. Anyway, fixed now. And best of luck in your master's!

Comment: Hi @billisphere! I still have a problem. Your code works very well, but... do you have any ideal why the error NDSolveValue::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x == 0.`. ? This error is related to the the function tmedNum[x,t] because if I set tmedNum=0 or any constant, there is no problem.

Comment: @LuisFernandoMoura, I'm not sure unfortunately, since I don't encounter that error here. In the code above, `tmedNum` is permanently defined to always "hand off" to `tmed`, so I can only guess a problem would be with whatever current function that `tmed` is defined as during the iteration in which you see that error. Try enabling the Debugger (under the Evaluation menu) and enable "Break at Messages" and "Show Stack", then run your code again. When the message occurs and the stack window fills, inspect the value of `tmed` to verify its value is what you were expecting.

Comment: p @billisphere, the problem is... even though it was defined  tmedNum[x_?NumericQ, t_NumericQ] := tmed[x, t], if you evaluate tmedNum doing NumericQ[tmedNum], the output is "False". What's the best way to solve this? I don't know. Maybe creating an interpolation function from a table, but this way sounds to be an alternative not so smart.

Comment: @LuisFernandoMoura, I'm not sure what the expression `NumericQ[tmedNum]` is trying to accomplish, but yes, it should evaluate to `False` because `tmedNum` is only a symbol denoting part of a transformation rule, not itself a numeric value.

Answer (score 3):

The following set of expressions, which is taken from the relevant part of your code and simplified for discussion purposes, causes infinite recursion.

```
tpred[x_, t_] := .6 tmedpred[x, t] + .4 med[x, t]; 
tmed[x_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := tpred[x, t]; 
tmedpred = tmed
```

`tpred` is defined in terms of `tmedpred`. `tmed` is defined in terms of `tpred`. Then `tmedpred` is made a synonym for `tmed`, making `tpred` a function of itself. Do you not see the circularity of this?

Comment: Yes @m_goldber. Question: Is it possible to create a function (tmed) that keep its original behavior but is not connected to the other functions (tmedpred and med)? I kind of numerical function? Sorry if the question sounds to be silly.

Comment: @LuisFernandoMoura. I would like to help you more, but I am not sure that I can. It has be 50 years since I last worked with PDEs. What little I recall about solving them is very much out of date. I can follow your code well enough to see the circular definitions I pointe out, but I don't fully understand it.